# Angular-slider mobile issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, slider

I am using the following directive: https://venturocket.github.io/angular-slider/

From that i have the following HTML:

```
<slider ng-model="skill.answer" ng-init="skill.answer = 0" floor="1" ceiling="10" class="m-b-sm"></slider>
```

And this works well on a desktop however once i go down to mobile i am unable to slide the slider.

Has anyone tried this and have a fix for it?

Comment: No console output? You added angular-touch? What browser and version? Please, add more details.

Comment: There are a [opened issue on github](https://github.com/Venturocket/angular-slider/issues/54) about this with a workaround description. It seems to me that the project is no longer maintained.